# Can We Pass Multiple Parameters To A Function In Controller?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, controller, arguments

I am using codeigniter. I have a view file where i choose a employee and send the id using form action and select services that a employee can perform and store them in a table.I have inserted the employee id and service id. Now i need to insert employee name.
My controller file is

```
 class admin_service_limitation extends CI_Controller{
    public function services()
        {
    $id = $this->session->userdata('employee');
    $id_array = $this->input->post("services");
//I need to get the employee name here and store them in a table along with employee id and service id
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($id_array); $i++) {
        if(isset($id_array[$i])&& $id_array[$i]!=""){
        $data_to_store = array('employee_id' => $id, 'service_id' => $id_array[$i]);
        $this->add_service_model->save($data_to_store);
       }
    }
    $data['addservice'] = $this->add_service_model->get_addservices();
    $data['main_content'] = 'admin/service_limitation/newview';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

    }
```

Here i am getting the employee id and service id and store them in a table.That table contains fields like `employee_id`,`employee_name` and `service_id`.
My model file:

```
class sample_model extends CI_Model{

 function store_service($data)
    {
        $insert = $this->db->insert('service', $data);
        return $insert;
}
}
```

Here i wrote a function that i use to insert into the `addservice` table. I get all the data to be stored as array and save them in the `addservice` table.
My view file where i choose a employee. 
`select.php`

```
 <?php          
      echo form_open('admin/service_limitation/service_view/'.$this->uri->segment(4).'', $attributes);
      ?>

     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="header">Employee id</th>
                <th class="yellow header headerSortDown">First name</th>
                <th class="green header">Last name</th>
                <th class="red header">Email</th>
                <th class="red header">Chair renter</th>

                <th class="red header">Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
              foreach($employee as $row)
              {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_first_name'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_last_name'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['emp_email_id'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$row['chair_renter'].'</td>';



                echo '<td class="crud-actions">
                  <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/service_limitation/service_view/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-info">Select employee</a>  

                </td>';
                echo '</tr>';
              }
              ?>      
            </tbody>
          </table> 
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

In this view i have a form once i submit the form employee id will be sent to the controller function, Here i need to send employee name now.. Can some one help me code?
Another view where i choose services is:
`service_view.php`

```
            <?php

            $attributes = array('class' => 'form-inline reset-margin', 'id' => '');
 echo form_open('admin/service_limitation/newview', $attributes);

            ?>             
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="header">Service id</th>
                <th class="yellow header headerSortDown">Service name </th>
                <th class="green header">Service catogary</th>
                <th class="red header">Service tax</th>
                <th class="red header">Service length</th>
                <th class="red header">Service price</th>
                <th class="red header">Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
              foreach($service as $row)
              {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_name'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['category'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_tax'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_length'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['service_price'].'</td>';
                echo '<td class="crud-actions">
                 <input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['id'].'" name="services[]"/>

                </td>';
                echo '</tr>';
              }
              ?>      
            </tbody>
          </table>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
            <button class="btn" type="reset">Cancel</button>
    </div>
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The above view calls the services function in my controller file by which I can save data such as the employee id from the first view and services id from the second view.

**Edit 01**

```
public function select_service($id)
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
         $this->session->set_userdata('employee', $id);

    $data['service'] =   $this->add_service_model->get_services();  
            $data['main_content'] = 'admin/service_limitation/service_view';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  

    }
```

This is a function where i get the employee id as session variable and use them in selection function i have above. is it possible to get the employee name like I got employee_id.

Comment: Cant understand Question

Comment: i need to send my employee name along with employee id.here, <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/service_limitation/service_view/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-info">Select employee</a>

Comment: in `.$row['id']` it pass all the data to table so how you can pick one?? or else use dropdown

Comment: if it passes all data can i get employee name here?

Comment: no way. or prompt text box first to enter emp number or name.(must be unique) . when user enter correct load relevant employee data.

Comment: i have given u edit 01 can you please verify it...

Comment: I think you want to send multiple service ids (not fixed), whichever is checked by checkbox (As shown in second view ) to a function in controller. right?

Comment: hmm i just used array to get multiple values. but i need employee name

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what is your problem clearly, but in general why you don't try to get employ name with his ID that you already got it ?

Comment: that's what i am not aware of. I do not know how to get the employee name and employee id @Amr

Comment: There is two ways to do that in general: if you manage POST\GET requests you can put the name in hidden field with ID in normal one, Or what about get the name via ID with model\controller ?

Comment: can you give me some code snippet

Comment: Check : [Adding Hidden Input Fields](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html), If you're stuck there I suggest you to make your code and problem description more defined, clear and tidy so I can give efficient help

Answer (score 1):

Multiple parameters can be passed into a controller function by adding additional URL segments.  You may need to set up the route for this to happen in application/config/routes.php.

The [CodeIgniter documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods) mentions how to do this, and how it all works.

If that doesn't match what you are after specifically, and the parameters aren't always the same number in length, then you're going to need to use form to send the data, and use `$this->input...` to get the data you want to use in the function

Comment: I just need to know how to pass multiple values such as employee name,address,phone number.. to controller function from a view file. <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/service_limitation/service_view/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-info">Select employee</a> In this code how could all needed values

Comment: To do what you're asking, you should just need to make the URL larger to be in the format `controller/function/name/address/phone number

Comment: In this <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/service_limitation/service_view/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-info">Select employee</a> I need to post the employee name along with emp_id..site_url("admin").'/service_limitation/service_view/'.$row['id']..How to add it in this place

Comment: From what you have said, i think there are two options: 1) when you go to the page and pass the user ID, then you load the details from the database (if they already exist) and store them elsewhere.  If you're sending new details, each link row should be a form of its own so the details can be submitted.

Comment: Yo don't need forms. Add more elements to the url in the <a> link you're generating on the webpage like: <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/service_limitation/service_view/'.$row['id'].'/'.$row['employee_name'].'" class="btn btn-info">Select employee</a>

Comment: Are you wanting to call the function in the controller via an http request or just use a function from that controller? If it's the http request then just like everyone is saying, set up a route with all the extra params in the url so you can parse them. If you're just wanting to call on a function (private) that exists in the controller, then simply bind a variable to the view named 'this' and set it to $this in the controller. Then in the view just call on $this->function('arg1', 'arg2') and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As  NetVicious mentioned,You can pass the attributes in url itself as below-

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('member/addcard/'.$member->customer_id.'/'.$member->customer_mobile); ?>" class="btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-plus"><strong style="color: #dddddd;">Add Card</strong></a>
```

And in the controller you can call it as-

```
function addcard($id,$phone) {
//Your Code
}
```

This worked fine for me.

OR
you can add `data-pricetag="<?= $treatments->treatment_price?>" data-customer="<?= $member->customer_type?>"` something similar like this in your input tag and call a function onlick.
Then

```
function update_price(e) {  
//  $('#treatment').on('change',function () {

  var price = 0;

    $(#yourid, $(e)).click(function(){
     //console.log($(this).data('pricetag'));
     //You get the values here
     price += $(this).data('pricetag');
     //price += parseInt( $(this).next().text())  
     var cust_type =  $(this).data('customer'); 

jQuery.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
          // dataType: 'html',
          //dataType: "json",
          data: your parameters,
           async:true,
        url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'member/memberPack/'; ?>",

       success: function(data)
       {
           console.log(data);
            //$("#price").html("");

        $("#price").val(data.package_price);
        $("#session").val(data.package_session);

       }
    });
```

});
}

This is just a layout of my idea,you need to try out.Sorry if any mistakes.

Comment: passing this large values with the url will be a good practice?

Comment: if this is not secret credentials you can follow this,or either you can do using ajax and can pass the data.

Comment: ajax? How to do it. Can you help me please?

Comment: i have added along the answer,sorry if any mistakes.This is just an idea what i had.

Comment: Prefer the first method since simple,easy and less code.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve your query(other than sending as uri segment):-

1. You pass only ID ,do this thing like when you insert in your DB:-

   `INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_TABLE(employee_id, employee_name, service_id) SELECT $employee_id,(SELECT employee_name  from employee_table where employee_id=$employee_id),$service_id`

   2. You can submit your form through `AJAX` :-

> ```
> ("#employee_form").submit(function(e) {   
>                   base_url=<?php your_base_url ?>
>                     e.preventDefault();
>                     $.ajax({
>                         type : "POST",
>                         url : base_url+"controller_name/function",
>                         data : $("#employee_form").serialize(),
>                         success : //do anything
>                     });
>                 });
> ```

Now in your controller, you can retrieve your data by post i.e.:-

```
$this->input->post('employee_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your first form get the employee details.
when you store that employee id  you can select also employee name.
and store it as the id.

but if you want it another way you need to get your employee details like name, id and pass them as:

```
$data['employee_id'] = your employee id;
$data['employee_name'] = your employee name;
```

in this way in your service_view.php 
you got two new variables.

$employee_id : which is your employee id;
$employee_name : which is your employee name.

then when you need to pass them to any action just pass them as any link in your site.

```
site_url() . 'Controller_Name/Method_name/'.$employee_id.'/'.$employee_name;
```

and so on :)